# gossip-based kubernetes cluster and spring-cloud-kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud

I am reading these urls:
http://blog.christianposta.com/microservices/netflix-oss-or-kubernetes-how-about-both/

Christian Posta's article sounded to me like if you are using kubernetes you need not worry about service discovery, self registration, loadbalancing using netflix because a whole lot of that is built into kubernetes already. He said Netflix OSS is not needed with kubernetes. That said he also encourages us to look into https://github.com/spring-cloud-incubator/spring-cloud-kubernetes. 
No doubts so far.
I have a working Kubernetes gossip-based cluster deployed on AWS using Kops. 
Since this is not a DNS based cluster does that mean i will not be able to use spring-cloud-kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it.
There is no such limitation at least for DiscoveryClient.
Just thought maybe this might be useful to others.